# Update SSIS configuration table or filter using script task?

Tags: c#, ssis

One area where SSIS package configuration falls short is having the ability to update the configuration table or configuration filter with an expression.  It would be beneficial to have logic determine what configuration table should be selected when using one server with one sql instance for multiple environments, DEV, TEST etc.

When dealing with multiple servers SSIS excels but with one server and one instance this is a limitation. Has anyone tired using a script task and c# to pull change the configuration table  on the fly?

Comment: Could you help me better understand the challenges you face? You are using configuration via SQL Server table. Are you trying to share a single configuration table across dev/test/prod environments?

Comment: Yes, using SQL Server configuration table. I want to share a single configuration table across environments (one server though) but be able to modify the configuration filter (PACKAGENAME_DEV vs PACKAGENAME_PROD etc.) at run-time.

Comment: Dtexec does not support changing an entire Package Configuration at runtime. What is possible is to use the SSIS Object model in PowerShell or C# to make this change after loading the Package into memory and before executing it, but that would require you writing and calling this "shim" to run your packages instead of using dtexec directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the configuration information in an environment variable outside of the package (note the second option in the dialog:)

[image]

And it's fairly straightforward to modify environment variables with a Powershell script.

Of course, if you're on SSIS 2012 or later, I'd strongly recommend you switch over to project configuration vs. package configuration so you can take advantage of the IS Catalog, which gives you a lot more developer-friendly control over how your SSIS packages and projects are configured, deployed, and executed.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to have a little batch job that will copy the correct config file to the expected location before running the package.  In fact, the job could copy the dev/test/prod config file over, and then run the package.  (No, I haven't tried this, but I do this by hand when I'm developing.  I have separate config files and just move in the one I want to use before opening and running the package.)

Comment: I see what you are saying, but in my case I'm using the SQL Server configuration table to store my settings.  I also have a xml config file that based on the machine I'm on will automatically point to the correct environment, so I never have to worry about running a package against a production environment. My issue is I want the ability to change the sql configuration filter, so I can use one sql table for multiple environments if required.